# sequelize is not defined (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, sequelize.js

I'm new to nodejs, trying to make an API by walking through the guide, but got an issue I can't resolve even with google tho. 
Here's my command line text.

```
consign v0.1.2 Initialized in d:\Jinn\API
+ .\libs\config.js
+ .\db.js
+ .\libs\middlewares.js
+ .\routes\index.js
+ .\routes\tasks.js
+ .\libs\boot.js
d:\Jinn\API\db.js:22
    sequelize = new _sequelize2.default(config.database, config.username, config
.password, config.params);
              ^

ReferenceError: sequelize is not defined
    at Function.module.exports (d:/Jinn/API/db.js:10:5)
    at Consign.into (d:\Jinn\API\node_modules\consign\lib\consign.js:239
:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:/Jinn/API/index.js:13:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at loader (d:\Jinn\API\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5
)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (d:\Jinn\API\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at d:\Jinn\API\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\_babel-node.js:161:27
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\Jinn\API\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\_babel
-node.js:162:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! api@1.0.0 start: `babel-node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the api@1.0.0 start script 'babel-node index.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bitskinsapi package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     babel-node index.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs api
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls api
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     d:\Jinn\API\npm-debug.log
```

Seems that troubles are somewhere in db.js file so here is the code of it:

```
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import Sequelize from "sequelize";

let db = null;

module.exports = app => {
  if (!db) {
    const config = app.libs.config;
    sequelize = new Sequelize(
      config.database,
      config.username,
      config.password,
      config.params
    );

    db = {
     sequelize,
     Sequelize,
     models: {}
    };

    // Загрузка моделей
    const dir = path.join(__dirname, "models");
    fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
      const modelDir = path.join(dir, file);
      const model = sequelize.import(modelDir);
      db.models[model.name] = model;
    });

    Object.keys(db.models).forEach(key => {
      db.models[key].associate(db.models);
    });
  }

  return db;
};
```

To tell the truth I mostly followed instructions and copy-pasted code fragments that's why I'm frustrated because it should work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Didn't declared `sequelize`, just declare it,  `const sequelize = `

Comment: You mean add "const" word before "sequelize" in "sequelize = new Sequelize(" ?